# How to write this to a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

A procedure of animal feed makes two food products: F1 and F2. The products contain three major ingredients: M1, M2, and M3. Each ton of F1 requires 200 pounds of M1, 100 pounds of M2, and 100 pounds of M3. Each ton of F2 requires 100 pounds of M1, 200 pounds of M2, and 400 pounds of M3. There are at least 5000 pounds of M1 available, at least 7000 pounds of M2 available, and at least 10000 pounds of M3 available. Each ton of F1 costs $450 to make, and each ton of F2 costs $300 to make. How many tons of each food product should the producer make to minimize cost? What is the minimum cost?

Can I still use simplex method for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like, that it is a good idea to apply the simplex algorithm. Just try it. I do some groundwork for you.

Defining the variables:

$x_1:=\texttt{amount of $F_1$ (in tons)}$

$x_2:=\texttt{amount of $F_2$ (in tons)}$

$y_1:=\texttt{amount of $M_1$ (in pounds)}$

$y_2:=\texttt{amount of $M_2$ (in pounds)}$

$y_3:=\texttt{amount of $M_3$ (in pounds)}$

The objective function is:

$\texttt{min} \ \ 450x_1+300x_2$

And the constraints are:

$x_1=200y_1$

$x_1=100y_2$

$x_1=100y_3$

$x_2=100y_1$

$x_2=200y_2$

$x_2=400y_3$

$y_1 \leq 5,000$

$y_2 \leq 7,000$

$y_3 \leq 10,000$

$y_1,y_2,y_3 \geq 0$

Every single equation requiress an artificial variable. And every single $\leq$-equation requiress a slack variable. Thus the simplex tableau is

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline x_1&x_2&y_1&y_2&y_3 &a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4&a_5&a_6&s_1&s_2&s_3&RHS \\ \hline 450&300&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 1&0&-200&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 1&0&0&-100&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 1&0&0&0&-100&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 0&1&-100&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 0&1&0&-200&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 0&1&0&0&-400&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\ \hline 0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&5,000 \\ \hline 0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&7,000 \\ \hline 0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&10,000 \\ \hline \end{array}$

The coefficients of the first row should be all non-positive at the end.